# the sum of a float array consisting large and small elements

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, sum, precision

I was asked this question during a java interview: I was required to figure out the sum of the elements in a float array. The elements, however, consist both very large and very small numbers, the question is, how can I guarantee  the accuracy of the summary?

I guess it requires some decent understanding about Float implementation in Java, which I unfortunately lack of, or is this a reasonable question?

Comment: this is a question made to figure out if you knew what floating-point numbers were and when to use them.  As you can see by most answers here, most programmers don't have a clue about these ;)  Besides the excellent answer by Ted Hopp, I suggest reading the 80 pages .pdf that used to be hosted on Sun's website: *What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetics"...  Programmers that are not scientist should remember the following: don't use floating-point numbers unless you've read that paper and understand Ted Hopp's answer and why the others are so wrong.

Comment: @Syntax Error I assume you mean the goldberg paper? That's shorter than 80pages though (and the really important parts are at the beginning). Anyways - anyone with a Master in CS that hasn't read that particular paper or learned about the basics presented in that paper somewhere else should be ashamed. I get access through my ACM subscription but possibly there's a copy on suns site.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what the interviewer was after was a basic understanding of floating point roundoff. Adding from smallest to largest (magnitude) numbers gives the least roundoff error, so the first step is to sort the array accordingly. You can then impress the interviewer by also recommending the use of [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: +1 - the only one a) really answering the question and b) with an understanding about fp accuracy.

Comment: Is there an algorithm that chooses to sum a (sorted) list by adding the smallest two elements together, and then reinserting the sum into the list, rather than accumulating the sum? I guess the overhead of maintaining the list (or maybe a tree) would be more than the extra arithmetic involved in the Kahan summation algorithm.

Comment: Also, all of the methods seem to assume that the numbers are all positive. How do you deal with sets of numbers of mixed sign?

Comment: as an additional note the numbers will need to be sorted by the absolute value

Comment: @Neil, @ratchet - the sort is by magnitude (absolute value) of the number.

Comment: @Neil I don't see why you think that Kahan's algorithm will only work correctly with positive numbers?

Comment: @Voo Sorry, it wasn't obvious enough to me, but I believe you.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). This type is able to hold arbitrarily large values.

Basic example of how to do such sum:

```
public BigDecimal sum(float[] floats) {
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    for (float aFloat : floats) {
        sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(aFloat));
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If performance can be sacrificed for precision, you could convert the floats to BigDecimals and sum the latter.

Answer (score -2):

In you case you can use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) java type.